# Angularjs Directive Delegate not firing through intermediary handler

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have just spent 4 hours trying to implement a directive with a delegate, with no luck.

Use Case:

I have a directive called "filter".

When the user activates/deactivates the filters the parent scope may want to update the data on the screen.

Before I let the parent run, i want to make some internal changes to an internal data structure and pass the new filter state through to the parent.

I have created a jsfiddel to show a simplified version of what i am trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/concept/zADNy/
Here is my scope in the directive

```
scope : {
    onFilterChanged : '&'
},
```

Here is the intermediary handler

```
function notifyParent() {
    scope.onFilterChanged({filters:scope.filters});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Directive Delegates are must be lower case** (someone please correct me if that statment is wrong, and if so, then why did the camel case version not work)

Ok so after hours of playing and reading and looking at other people's code, i found out that for some reason the delegate functions need to be lowercase.

Here is the resulting fix

http://jsfiddle.net/concept/zADNy/4/

Here is my scope in the directive

```
scope : {
    onfilterchanged : '&'
},
```

Here is the intermediary handler

```
function notifyParent() {
    scope.onfilterchanged({filters:scope.filters});
}
```

Comment: `onFilterChanged` property is looking for a `on-filter-changed=""` attribute in your template. Camelcase becomes dashed case in angular land. That's why your didn't work.

Comment: Does anyone else hate that feature?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess its basic convention. You can not name variable in javascript like on-filter-changed. This will be either on_filter_changed or onFilterChanged. In JS world, the second is more in use.