# How to call a function on a directive scope from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've searched all over the internet and cannot find a solution please help!

```
directive('menu',function(){
    return{
        link : function(scope,element,attrs){
            scope.foo = function(){
            alert('test!');
            }
        },
        controller : function($scope){
            $scope.foo();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The `link` function you have here is the `post-linking` function; however, the controller is instantiated *before* the `pre-linking` phase, so `$scope.foo` isn't available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delay the call to `foo()` using `$evalAsync()`:

```
controller : function($scope){
    $scope.$evalAsync(function() {
        $scope.foo();
        console.log($scope);
    });
}
```

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/T6JMy/)</kbd>

You could also use `$timeout()` instead of `$evalAsync()`.  Both allow the link function to execute first.

Comment: Thanks very much m8! This worked perfectly! and just to clarify i'm doing it this was as i'm working with a menu toggle directive plugin and it binds click within the directive.. I don't want it to do this, i want it to be swipe instead of click and for it to activate when hm-swipe="menu()" is activated for a mobile application through Phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

As Ye Liu said, your controller *calls* your directive's compile and then link functions. 
From the angular directive doc (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

> The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase

The controller will be within the scope of your app, and once the post-link function finishes, your directive will be a child of this scope. Consider that the link function's purpose is to bind model data to your template and set watches for bound variables, not to create a discreet 'directive object'.

If you are trying to set the foo function inside of the link function in order to access directive scope variables, take a look at directive delegate functions and bound variables in the "scope:" directive attribute. The angular directive tutorial gives a somewhat obtuse version of this as its final example ("zippy"), and [Angularjs Directive Delegate not firing through intermediary handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344297/angularjs-directive-delegate-not-firing-through-intermediary-handler) gives an example of a delegate function you can invoke from your template itself.

Comment: The way the OP wrote the directive, there is no new child scope.  See my answer/fiddle -- expand the $scope that is logged by the directive's controller and you'll see that the directive does not create a new scope -- it is the same scope as MyCtrl.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Hmm - I suppose my issue is really more one of intent than  technical possibility. As you say, without using the "scope" attribute  the link and controller share a scope (and all of its components) - so at that point why not just set the function in the controller and avoid the async call?

Comment: Setting the function in the controller would be a good way to solve this problem (and I would recommend this approach over what I provided in my answer). However, I'm not sure if the OP needs to implement it the way shown for some reason or not.