# Angular JS - Call a Directive function in an outside Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am newbie in Angular JS, so probably my issue is quite simple, but actually I haven't found a solution for it.

I would like to know if it is possible to access a function (inside the link function in a directive) from an external controller. I am working with a Directive that control some variables required for the directive, and I need to access one of the from the controller. I was trying to create a function in the directive as:

```
    scope.testArray = [{id=1, text="test1"},{id=2, text="test2"}];        
    scope.getTestArray = function () {
          return scope.testArray()
    };
```

And from my controller I want to call it like this:

```
    var testArray = scope.getTestArray()
```

But it says that the getTestArray does not exists for the element (scope). I assumed this is because the changes over the scope variable inside the directive, are not visible from the controller. So, Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Thanks for the help you can give me

Comment: Why are you using a function? You can simply do `var testArray = $scope.testArray;`

Comment: I Agree with Codezille. Make use of two way binding. In the directive use the '=' symbol. This way you can modify the array inside and outise your directive and both parties share the same object.

Comment: directives are designed to implement DOM specific functionality.  for example ng-repeat repeats a particular chunk of html with dynamic data.  Are you sure you shouldnt be using a service instead?  I need a bit more context that your example code to give a specific answer

Comment: @Anton I have read about the services, and maybe I will consider them. What I am trying to do is get the value of that array that is modified in the directive, in my controller. But it seems that what I'm doing is kinda overrating (to no say completely wrong)

Comment: @Codezilla Yes. Actually this works! It is better in this way ! Thanks. I forgot to define the variable in the directive. I was first, defining it in the Controller, but the idea is just get the value that the directive is handling. That is why it always says undefined.. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You controller gets instantiated before the directive gets loaded. You can simply delay the call to the directive function by doing:

```
$timeout(function(){
    var testArray = $scope.getTestArray()
},1000);
```

Or you dont need to wrap it in a function. Simply do this:

```
$timeout(function(){
    var testArray = $scope.testArray;
},1000);
```

Comment: you are probably right on the instantiating.  but that is kinda like the symptom rather than the actual problem

Comment: You can also use $evalAsync() instead of $timeout: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17795815/215945